# SwiftUI Text being truncated when set to resist?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following component:

```
Text(booking.endDate!, style: .relative)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.jpGreen))
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

This is a countdown to a date formatted as hours and minutes, however in the interface it is randomly truncated at irregular intervals such as this

[image]

If i have applied fixed size attributes, how can i go further to make it never truncate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale text to fit parent view with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035746/how-to-scale-text-to-fit-parent-view-with-swiftui)

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12 with just code snapshot in ContentView. Would you give more context?

Comment: its in a VStack and theres 2 VStack in an HStack, if that helps, im brand new to swiftui so unsure what info is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this by adding
`.allowsTightening(true)` to your text.

> Applying it may not even fully work depending on just how much space
> can be tightened.

Source : [Mark Moeykens's book](https://www.bigmountainstudio.com/courses/free-swiftui-book)

**EDIT:** Also you can allow SwiftUI to scale your text to fit the available space.

Try using [minimumScaleFactor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/minimumscalefactor(_:)) for example, it takes a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: I added another option to the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about simply add .padding(.horizontal) to the end just like this.

```swift
Text("...").padding(.horizontal)
```