# Why isn't text box expanding to fit text

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, vstack

I have a VStack that contains multiple lines of text, but for some reason the second line of text won't expand to fit the frame

[image]

My code is shown below - it's actually pretty simple.

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("PS5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.top, 10.0)
            
            Text("A Sony Playstation 5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.top, 10.0)
                
            
            Text("PS5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.vertical, 10.0)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 120.0)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 90))
```

Comment: `VStack(alignment: .leading)`

Comment: This isn't the original question you posted.  Don't completely change a question once it is active.  Delete it and write a new one.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the `.trailing` padding on your entire `VStack`. Notice how no text goes beyond. Remove the padding, reduce its size, or [scale it to fit the size given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57044002/18457910). Take a look at the example code below - this removes the .padding on that trailing edge.

```swift
 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("PS5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.top, 10.0)
            
            Text("A Sony Playstation 5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.top, 10.0)
                
            
            Text("PS5").font(.custom("Kufam Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(CustomColor.lightGrey)
                .padding(.vertical, 10.0)
            
            Spacer()
        }
   .frame(width: .infinity, height: 120.0)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
//Important parts. Either reduce the frame size, or reduce the padding like here.
```