# SwiftUI picker scale to fit selection

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a picker like the following that has a frame width of 150. I need the text to fit inside the picker, but the `lineLimit()`, `scaledToFit()` and `scaledToFill()` do not do anything on the picker object.

```
@State var Status: String = ""

Picker(selection: $Status, label:
        Text("Status")) {
            Text("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy").tag(0)
                .lineLimit(2).scaledToFit().scaledToFill()
            Text("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz").tag(1)
                .lineLimit(2).scaledToFit().scaledToFill()
        }.frame(maxWidth: 150, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50, alignment:.center)
         .background(Color.gray)
         .lineLimit(2)
         .scaledToFit()
```

What is the correct way to scale and fit selected text inside the picker?

[image]

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: I have never found a way to wrap long selections. You can get to the choices, but not the label that displays the actual selection. You can, however, prevent it from running outside of the `.frame()` by placing `.clipped()` after. It will cut the end off the selection if the `.frame()` isn't wide enough, but it will keep it in bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to figure out how to do it with the picker object in SwiftUI, so I ended up creating a custom picker view that resizes the selected value in the frame.

```
struct PickerView: View{
    @State var picking: Bool = false
    @State var Status: String = ""
    @State var ValueList = ["yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                             "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                             "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    var body: some View{
        CustomPicker(picking: $picking, Status: $Status, ValueList: $ValueList).onTapGesture{
            picking = true
        }
    }
}

struct CustomPicker: View{
    @Binding var picking: Bool
    @Binding var Status: String
    @Binding var ValueList: [String]
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            HStack{
                if Status == "" {
                    Text("Pick Value")
                } else {
                    Text(Status).lineLimit(2)
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: 150, minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50, alignment:.center)
            .background(Color.gray)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $picking, content: {
            ForEach(ValueList, id: \.self){ item in
                Text(item).onTapGesture {
                    Status = item
                    picking = false
                }.foregroundColor(Color.blue).padding().border(Color.gray)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

You tap to pick a value

[image]

You can then select a value

[image]

And it displays correctly within the box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try rather using `scaleToFill` with a `lineLimit` of `1`.

Check out [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link/scaledtofill())
Another good [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035746/how-to-scale-text-to-fit-parent-view-with-swiftui?rq=1)

Example:

```
Text("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy").tag(0).lineLimit(1).scaledToFill()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either. I'll look through the other stack overflow post and try those solutions.